# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community - Unable to connect to the configured development Web server' error when trying to build website

Tags: http, visual-studio-2015

I know it's a re-post but I've tried so many different solutions and so far nothing fixed my problem.

I'm having an annoying issue with my Microsoft Visual Studio 2015:

Every time I build my project, I get an alert message saying "Unable to connect to the configured development Web server".

I had an issue when I tried to install MVS 2015 at first but fixed it by disabling the HTTP driver in device manager. After that everything worked great for a week or so, I only had to able/disable the HTTP driver depending on what I wanted to work on. Since today, disabling HTTP doesn't change anything and I always get the same alert message.

My set-up:

- HP EliteBook 8560w
- Windows 7 professional with Service Pack 1
- Intel Core i7-2630QM @ 2.00GHz
- 8.00 GB of RAM
- 64-bit Operating System

What I've done:

- Disabled/Enabled HTTP driver
- Install every windows update (windows 7 pro)
- Install every MSV 2015 update
- Uninstall/Install IIS Express
- Delete the automatically generated IIS Express Folder
- Inserting this command in Command Shell
  netsh http add urlacl url=http://{ip_addr}:{port}/ user=everyone
- Opening MVS in administrator
- Look if SSL was enabled (it wasn't)
- Closing skype or any apps using IIS Express
- Close Chrome
- And probably more since I got to page 4 of google's results when I searched for this error message.

So yeah, I'm pretty clueless about what to try next, I've read somewhere that installing windows 10 could fix it but I have my doubts about that.

If anyone has any solutions or anything to help me troubleshoot the problem it would be SUPER appreciated!

Thanks,

C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I should of done a while ago but I forgot, managed to make it work by installing Windows 10.